# My PyAutoGUI script is raising TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable after calling locateOnScreen()

Tags: python, python-3.x, coordinates, pyautogui

I wrote a python program that takes a screenshot and looks for a .PNG image in the given region and clicks on that picture if it's there. I am using the library pyautogui.

```
while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:

    pic = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(360,158,1900,1025))

    width, height = pic.size

    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('greenlightning.png', region=(360,158,1900,1025), grayscale=True, confidence=0.8) != None:
        lightningloc = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('greenlightning.png')
        x = lightningloc[0]
        y = lightningloc[1]
        pyautogui.click(x, y - 50)
        time.sleep(0.2)
    else:
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

The problem is that it sometimes throws me a TypeError because "x" or "y" is 'NoneType'.

```
  File "C:\****\**\***\***\****.py", line 18, in <module>
    x = lightningloc[0] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I just want the program to click on a pixel that is 50 pixels higher than the coordinates of my image `'greenlightning.png'`. Do you have any idea about the `pyautogui.click()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the first `locateOnScreen()` call returns coordinates but the second call returns `None`. The `[0]` in `lightningloc[0]` is called a **subscript**. The error message is telling you that you tried to subscript a value of `NoneType`. `lightningloc` is the variable being subscripted. `None` is the only value with a type of `NoneType`, so `lightningloc` is `None`. Try calling `locateOnScreen()` once and assign it to a variable and then check for `None`, like this:

```
    lightningloc = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('greenlightning.png', region=(360,158,1900,1025), grayscale=True, confidence=0.8)
    if lightningloc is not None:
        x = lightningloc[0]
        y = lightningloc[1]
        pyautogui.click(x, y - 50)
        time.sleep(0.2)
    else:
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first call to `locateOnScreen()` uses the `confidence` keyword argument, allowing for a fuzzy match (when OpenCV is installed). The second time you call it, you aren't passing this keyword argument and PyAutoGUI is trying to do a pixel perfect match. That second call is failing to find a pixel perfect match, so it returns `None` which causes the error later.

Here's how you can change your code so that it doesn't do two separate calls to `locateOnScreen()`:

```
while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:

    pic = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(360,158,1900,1025))

    width, height = pic.size

    lightningloc = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('greenlightning.png', region=(360,158,1900,1025), grayscale=True, confidence=0.8)
    if lightningloc is not None:
        x = lightningloc[0]
        y = lightningloc[1]
        pyautogui.click(x, y - 50)
        time.sleep(0.2)
    else:
        time.sleep(0.1)
```